# Unsure how argument is being passed to parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm doing codecademy javascript. No programming experience. This lets me pass the round, but I don't understand how name is being argued here from the if statement to the function.

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Davidson",
        number: "555-555-5555",
        address: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        number: "666-666-6666",
        address: ['5', '6', '7', '8']
    }
};

var search = function(name) {
    for(var j in friends) {
        if(friends[j].firstName === name) {
            console.log(friends[j]);
            return friends[j];
        }
    }
};
```

Is it just hand holding or something? I put it in a document and it didn't log anything. `search();` and `search(friends.bill);` didn't log anything either. This is what it shows in their results sandbox:

```
{ firstName: 'Steve',
  lastName: 'Johnson',
  number: '666-666-6666',
  address: [ '5', '6', '7', '8' ] }
{ firstName: 'Steve',
  lastName: 'Johnson',
  number: '666-666-6666',
  address: [ '5', '6', '7', '8' ] }
{ firstName: 'Bill',
  lastName: 'Davidson',
  number: '555-555-5555',
  address: [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ] }
```

which seems wrong because Steve is repeated. Or Steve was logged/returned but Bill wasn't. But like I said it passed. I'm pretty confused.

---

My question is why does `friends[j].firstName === name` have any meaning to the search function? More specifically name. Simplifying/not iterating it, it's saying

```
if (friends.bill.firstName === name) {
  console.log(friends.bill);
  return friends.bill;
}
```

but where is `name` defined?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: to add: `search(friends.bill)` passes the `bill` object. You'd probably want to do `search(friends.bill.firstName)` or `search('Bill')` if you want to see a result.

Comment: `var search = function(name) {` ... this is where name is defined, it is a function  "argument" to the search function. perhaps you're confused about the `var search = function(name) {` syntax - it's equivalent to `function search(name) {`

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess I just don't know enough about functions. How are their first names equivalent to the entire function though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `name` is defined in the declaration of the function, as a parameter: `function(name) {`

That function will loop through the object `friends` and get all its properties, like `bill` and `steve` (they are also objects). Then, it will see if the `firstName` property of these objects are the same of the parameter you've sent to the function.

So, to see something logged into the console, you must call the function you've created and pass some existing name as a parameter, e.g:

```
search('Steve');
```

Then, it will log the entire `steve` object:

```
Object { firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Johnson", number: "666-666-6666", address: Array[4] }
```

Comment: Makes total sense. I was over complicating it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have one object with two persons in it and a search function `function search(name){...}` with an argument `name`,

try

```
search("Steve");
search(friends.steve.firstName);
search(friends.bill.firstName);
```

and check the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your function somewhere at the end:
 `search("Bill");`
...you only log something, if the search find something...

**Edit**
`name` is the parameter of your function, with `search("Bill")` you pass the string `"Bill"` to the function an `name` is in this case `"Bill"`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Davidson",
        number: "555-555-5555",
        address: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        number: "666-666-6666",
        address: ['5', '6', '7', '8']
    }
};

/*
So at this point you've just created an object called "friends"
and within it are two friends whose names are either "steve" or "bill"
*/

//------------------------------------------

/*
Then you create a function below and pass in the "parameter" name, which can really be anything, but I'm assuming it's being passed from some event.
*/

var search = function(name) {
    for(var j in friends) {
      /*
      Here, your for loop becomes a loop that loops for every instance in
      friends.  There are 2 friends, so your loop will execute twice for the
      two objects within your "friends" object, they are object 0, and object 1
      because arrays are a zero index object.
      */
        if(friends[j].firstName === name) {
          /*
          Here, you are saying to your function, that IF the friend object at
          the array index value of [j] (which will be 0, and then 1) matches
          the parameter(argument) passed in as "name" then log it, and 
          subsequently return the object values. If not, do nothing.
          */
            console.log(friends[j]);
            return friends[j];
          /*For example, if you passed your function(name){//do stuff here;}
          as function(bill){
               /* okay user, I've got this if statement which makes me loop
               the friends object and validate if I see something matching.
               .......is object 1 within friends "bill" ? YES!
                  ....then I'll pass obj.Bill back to the user (return) and
                    ..I'll show the user this as "console.log(friends[0])"
               .......is the next object "bill" ? No.
               .......are there anymore objects? No.  K, we're done.
               */
        }
    }
};

/* NOTE: Don't get confused with "j" as the looping variable as it's just going to continue for the length of the object it uses to validate your argument against.  If you had 50 names in obj.Friends then it'd loop 50 times as a zero index array (index of 0-49)
*/
```

I commented the code snippet above pretty heavily so you can see each stage of what is occurring in more details.  I hope it helps, I had issues with arrays and objects when I first started.... quite literally on the SAME site! ;)

Here is the same code in simplified terms:

```
var function = someFunction(parameter){ 
for(var counter = 0; counter < friends.length; friends +=1){
if( (friends[counter].bill ) || /*or*/ ( friends[counter].steve ) ){
return friends[counter];
console.log friends[counter];
}  
/* 
1 - "var functionName = function(parameter){ //do stuff };" is used
because it stores the function in memory and allows you to call it
from inside your web view, say on a button press you can use the button
press to provide "(name)" to be checked against all the objects in your
"friends" object."
2 - Using "name" as a generic parameter, and checking it against
all of the objects by name within "friends" just allows you to make
a virtually limitless searching feature.  It's good coding, although
at first it's hard to grasp why they do this.  But image you have a
search feature for an application like "Facebook" with 1 billion users.
3 - The function is stored in memory this way and will logically 
continue looping through the entire friends object until the
parameter given to the function, matches or not.  If it matches
it'll "return" it, and "log" it.
4 - Testing is paramount to becoming a good coder.  Typically, you'll
wireframe your functions like this and remove the console.log comments
upon release.
*/
```